# How to set static (first row is constant) row in dynamic datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I created dynamic table using bootstrap. i have a two rows. but now i want to **First row is static (constant)** and second row only having add new row button, if the button is clicked add a new row **the copy of elements second row only**..

> Simplify the question:
>
> ```
>   1. First row is static,
>
>   2. Second row only having add new row button,
>
>   3. If click add new row button the another row will come
>        that row having copy of second row elements or fields
> ```

Below my faild code..

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#add_row").on("click", function() {
    // Dynamic Rows Code

    // Get max row id and set new id
    var newid = 0;
    $.each($("#tab_logic tr"), function() {
      if (parseInt($(this).data("id")) > newid) {
        newid = parseInt($(this).data("id"));
      }
    });
    newid++;

    var tr = $("<tr></tr>", {
      id: "addr" + newid,
      "data-id": newid
    });

    // loop through each td and create new elements with name of newid
    $.each($("#tab_logic tbody tr:nth(0) td"), function() {
      var td;
      var cur_td = $(this);

      var children = cur_td.children();

      // add new td and element if it has a nane
      if ($(this).data("name") !== undefined) {
        td = $("<td></td>", {
          "data-name": $(cur_td).data("name")
        });

        var c = $(cur_td).find($(children[0]).prop('tagName')).clone().val("");
        c.attr("name", $(cur_td).data("name") + newid);
        c.appendTo($(td));
        td.appendTo($(tr));
      } else {
        td = $("<td></td>", {
          'text': $('#tab_logic tr').length
        }).appendTo($(tr));
      }
    });

    // add delete button and td
    /*
    $("<td></td>").append(
        $("<button class='btn btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-remove row-remove'></button>")
            .click(function() {
                $(this).closest("tr").remove();
            })
    ).appendTo($(tr));
    */

    // add the new row
    $(tr).appendTo($('#tab_logic'));

    $(tr).find("td button.row-remove").on("click", function() {
      $(this).closest("tr").remove();
    });
  });




  // Sortable Code
  var fixHelperModified = function(e, tr) {
    var $originals = tr.children();
    var $helper = tr.clone();

    $helper.children().each(function(index) {
      $(this).width($originals.eq(index).width())
    });

    return $helper;
  };

  $(".table-sortable tbody").sortable({
    helper: fixHelperModified
  }).disableSelection();

  $(".table-sortable thead").disableSelection();



  $("#add_row").trigger("click");
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<a id="add_row" class="btn btn-primary float-right adRow">Add New</a>
<div class="col-md-12 table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-sortable" id="tab_logic">
    <thead style="background-color: #680779;
                                                        color: #fff;">
      <tr>
        <th class="text-center">
          Account Code
        </th>
        <th class="text-center">
          A/c Name*
        </th>
        <th class="text-center">
          Narration*
        </th>
        <th class="text-center">
          Debit*
        </th>
        <th class="text-center">
          Credit
        </th>
        <th class="text-center" style="border-top: 1px solid #ffffff; border-right: 1px solid #ffffff;">
          Action
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="cashacc_code" placeholder='Name' class="form-control" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <select class="form-control" id="cashacc">
            <option value="">Select Option</option>
            <option value="1">JOE</option>
            <option value="2">Option 2</option>
            <option value="3">Option 3</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="acc_narrat" placeholder="Enter here" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#accnarratModal" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="cashdeb" placeholder='Name' data-action="sumDebit" class="form-control" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="cashcredit" placeholder='Name' class="form-control" readonly />
        </td>

        <td>
          <button class='btn btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-remove row-remove removeBtn'><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr id='addr0' class="hidden">
        <td data-name="cashCode">
          <input type="text" id="cashacc_code" name='cashacc_code' placeholder='Name' class="form-control" />
        </td>
        <td data-name="sel">
          <select class="form-control" name="sel0" id="cashacc">
            <option value="">Select Option</option>
            <option value="1">Option 1</option>
            <option value="2">Option 2</option>
            <option value="3">Option 3</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td data-name="narrate">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="acc_narrat" placeholder="Enter here" name="acc_narrat" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#accnarratModal" />
        </td>
        <td data-name="dbt">
          <input type="text" id="cashdeb" name='cashdeb' placeholder='Name' data-action="sumDebit" class="form-control" />
        </td>
        <td data-name="crdit">
          <input type="text" id="cashcredit" name='cashcredit' placeholder='Name' class="form-control" readonly />
        </td>

        <td data-name="del">
          <button name="del0" class='btn btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-remove row-remove removeBtn'><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

**[Fiddle Here](https://jsfiddle.net/56t8cd0f/1/)**

> Simplify:
>
> ```
>   1. First row is static,
>
>   2. Second row only having add new row button,
>
>   3. If click add new row button the another row will come
>        that row having copy of second row elements or fields
> ```

can you help me..?

Comment: The code snippet you have shared have an error  `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).sortable is not a function' fix it by adding jquery-ui.js cdn  and proceed .
Check your browser console for the error's you are getting that will give you more insight

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are creating a new elements by looping through td, you are referencing the 1st row (using `index` 0 )

```
$.each($("#tab_logic tbody tr:nth(0) td"), function() {
```

You need to reference 2nd row, using `index` 1

```
.each($("#tab_logic tbody tr:nth(1) td"), function() {
```

Here is the [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9m2xjuvw/)

Comment: yes sir, but still 3, 4, 5 something will come ,if i click add buttons

Comment: @Joe Updated Fiddle Link. Please check if this is what you need.

Comment: Exactly.. thanky you so much sir.. and can you tell me any websites to learn jQuery and ajax

Comment: Glad to help. If you are a beginner the w3schools is a good place to start.